# Fetching few elements using "$.[:2]" operator throws error in karate. might be a bug

Tags: karate

```
Example:
  Scenario: test
   * def response =
    """
    [
  "YEN01",
  "DP258",
  "SA661",
  "BT202",
  "UR809"
     ]
    """
    * def subset = response.[:2]
    * print subset
```

I tried response..[:2] . and also tried with enclosing in ().
Let me know if any one got this working.

Comment: sorry@PeterThomas. Just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding one character will fix your problem !

```
* def subset = $response.[:2]
```

Karate defaults to JavaScript and when you want JsonPath evaluation you need to give a little hint to Karate. This is explained in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get-short-cut